# Moving currency from data grid to text boxes to edit then back to data grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a program that uses datagrids to display tables from my database. To edit a details from the datagrid, I click the row and the data from that row populates in the my textboxes. I edit what I need to, click my save button and update my datagrid.

This works perfectly until I try to do this with a table that is using currency. I get the unhandled datatype mismatch error. Now I am pretty sure that is either because I have '£' symbol or because of the '.' as the amount is £4.99 but I am stuck on how to fix it so I can transfer this to the textboxes and edit correctly. Moving the data to the textboxes works fine but when I edit and save, I get the error.

Code for moving data from datagrid to textboxes:

```
// Displays Payment infomation in Update Area
        if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        {

        }
        else
        {
            if (paymentsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value != null)
            {
                textBox_cus_id_pay.Text = "" + paymentsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Payments_Customer_ID"].Value.ToString();
                textBox_amount.Text = paymentsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Amount"].Value.ToString();
                textBox_join_pay.Text = paymentsDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Join_Date"].Value.ToString();
            }
```

Code for updating datagrid after editing in textboxes:

```
 DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to update this payment? ", "Update Payment " + textBox_forename.Text + textBox_surname.Text, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {// Updates Product Info
            if (textBox_cus_id_pay.Text == "" || textBox_amount.Text == "" || textBox_join_pay.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please leave no boxes blank");
            }
            else
            {
                string payData = textBox_cus_id_pay.Text;
                command.CommandText = "UPDATE PayTable SET Payments_Customer_ID = '" + textBox_cus_id_pay.Text + "',  Amount = " + textBox_amount.Text + ", Join_Date = '" + textBox_join_pay.Text + "'";
                connect.Open();
                command.Connection = connect;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connect.Close();
                refreshPayments();
                MessageBox.Show("Payment Updated");
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly apprecited!

Comment: in your aspx markup can you use databound columns along with formatting? lookup how to use `DataFormatString` in the aspx page

Comment: @DJKRAZE Hmm I'm still pretty new to this. I don't know how do this. Is there a simple parse or something that I could add to my code?